# Can soda bread be successfully frozen, either baked or in dough form?

Tags: bread

I have to cook for one and soda bread is better for my diet.  Can it be frozen once baked, or in dough form so that I don't feel I have to pig out!?

Answer (score 5):

Soda bread is a simple quick bread, all of which freeze quite well after being baked (most yeast raised breads do as well).

Wrap it well to prevent freezer burn—I like to use a large sized freezer-rated zip type bag for freezing breads.

You can also put some waxed paper or parchment between each slice to help you get them out without thawing the whole loaf.